# Postgres query set priority to the where sentence

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a problem with my query

I have 2 tables:

```
1) Patient
*id: number
*name: varchar

2) Patient_coverage_list:
*item_id: number
*patient_id: number
*group_id: number
*start_date: date
*end_date: date
```

For example:

```
Patient
id | Name
1  | Mat 
2  | Michael

patient_coverage_list
item_id | patient_id | group_id | start_date | end_date
1       | 1          | 12       | 2012-12-12 | 2015-12-12
2       | 1          | 12       | 2008-12-12 | 2009-12-12
3       | 1          | 12       | 2017-12-12 | 2018-12-12
4       | 1          | 15       | 2020-12-12 | 2021-12-12
5       | 2          | 12       | 2016-12-12 | 2019-12-12
6       | 2          | 11       | 2017-12-12 | 2018-12-12
7       | 2          | 12       | 2021-12-12 | 2022-12-12
```

i have to select all the patient_coverage_list with the group_id is equal 12 and filter with a a dates but the filters need to be excluded for example:

**Scenario 1:**
if the current date is 2018-05-05 and the patient_coverage_list look like this its show the rows that is be between the start_date and end_date:

```
patient_coverage_list
item_id | patient_id | group_id | start_date | end_date
1       | 1          | 12       | 2012-12-12 | 2015-12-12
2       | 1          | 12       | 2008-12-12 | 2009-12-12
3       | 1          | 12       | 2017-12-12 | 2018-12-12
4       | 1          | 15       | 2020-12-12 | 2021-12-12
```

The patient that you show is the:

```
3|1| 12 | 2017-12-12 | 2018-12-12
```

**Scenario 2:** 
if the current date is 2018-05-05 and the patient_coverage_list look like this,
if the current is between the start_date and end_date it show the next date to be between:

```
patient_coverage_list
item_id | patient_id | group_id | start_date | end_date
1       | 1          | 12       | 2012-12-12 | 2015-12-12
2       | 1          | 12       | 2008-12-12 | 2009-12-12
4       | 1          | 15       | 2020-12-12 | 2021-12-12
```

The patient that you show is the:

```
4 | 1 | 15 | 2020-12-12 | 2021-12-12
```

**Scenario 3:** 
if the current date is 2018-05-05 and the patient_coverage_list look like this,
if the current is between the start_date and end_date and  is does not have a  next date it shows the row with the last date:

```
patient_coverage_list
item_id | patient_id | group_id | start_date | end_date
1       | 1          | 12       | 2012-12-12 | 2015-12-12
2       | 1          | 12       | 2008-12-12 | 2009-12-12
```

The patient that you show is the:

```
1       | 1          | 12       | 2012-12-12 | 2015-12-12
```

i created a query but i think that it can be better:

```
SELECT * FROM(
            SELECT pa.id, pa.name, pel.item_id, pel.patient_id, pel.group_id,  pel.start_date, pel.end_date         
            FROM patient pa 
            JOIN patient_coverage_list pel ON pel.patient_id  = pa.id 
            WHERE pel.group_id = $1 
            AND pel.item_id IN (SELECT peli.item_id 
                                FROM patient_coverage_list peli 
                                WHERE peli.patient_id = pel.patient_id 
                                AND peli.start_date < peli.end_date 
                                AND now() > peli.start_date 
                                AND now() < peli.end_date 
                                ORDER BY peli.end_date ASC 
                                LIMIT 1)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT pa.id, pa.name, pel.item_id, pel.patient_id, pel.group_id,  pel.start_date, pel.end_date         
            FROM patient pa 
            JOIN patient_coverage_list pel ON pel.patient_id  = pa.id  
            WHERE pel.group_id = $1 
            AND NOT (now() > pel.start_date AND now() < pel.end_date) 
            AND pel.start_date < pel.end_date 
            AND pel.item_id in (SELECT peli.item_id 
                                FROM seligibility.patient_eligibility_list peli 
                                WHERE peli.patient_id = pel.patient_id 
                                AND peli.start_date > now() 
                                ORDER BY peli.start_date DESC LIMIT 1) 
            AND pel.patient_id NOT IN (SELECT peli.patient_id 
                                        FROM seligibility.patient_eligibility_list peli 
                                        WHERE peli.patient_id = pel.patient_id 
                                        AND peli.start_date < peli.end_date 
                                        AND now() > peli.start_date 
                                        AND now() < peli.end_date 
                                        ORDER BY peli.end_date ASC LIMIT 1)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT pa.id, pa.name, pel.item_id, pel.patient_id, pel.group_id,  pel.start_date, pel.end_date         
            FROM patient pa 
            JOIN patient_coverage_list pel ON pel.patient_id  = pa.id   
            WHERE pel.group_id = $1 
            AND pel.start_date < pel.end_date 
            AND pel.item_id IN (SELECT peli.item_id 
                                FROM seligibility.patient_eligibility_list peli 
                                WHERE peli.patient_id = pel.patient_id 
                                AND now() > peli.end_date 
                                ORDER BY peli.end_date DESC LIMIT 1) 
            AND pel.patient_id NOT IN (SELECT peli.patient_id 
                                FROM seligibility.patient_eligibility_list peli 
                                WHERE peli.patient_id = pel.patient_id 
                                AND peli.start_date < peli.end_date 
                                AND now() > peli.start_date 
                                AND now() < peli.end_date 
                                ORDER BY peli.end_date ASC LIMIT 1) 
            AND pel.patient_id NOT IN (SELECT peli.patient_id 
                                        FROM seligibility.patient_eligibility_list peli 
                                        WHERE peli.patient_id = pel.patient_id 
                                        AND peli.start_date > now() 
                                        ORDER BY peli.start_date DESC LIMIT 1)) AS patient ORDER BY patient.id
```

Comment: Sorry but i don't see the logic behind your filter examples (especially 2nd). Could you describe logic of your filters? What about this filter with group_id =12 and then select customer from group_id=15?!?
It seems that your filter are: chose customer from group_id=n when now() between start_date end_date else choose customer with latest start_date. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason for nesting so many selects into one another. The given scenarios seem very simple. So, let's start with one by one, possibly precising what you meant below this answer.

**Scenario 1:** This seems easy. No need at all to do nested SELECT from `patient_coverage_list`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM patient AS pa
  JOIN patient_coverage_list AS pel ON pel.patient_id = pa.id
  WHERE pel.group_id = $1
    AND pel.end_date   > CURRENT_DATE  -- use CURRENT_DATE instead of NOW() if making date comparisons
    AND pel.start_date < CURRENT_DATE
  ORDER BY pel.end_date ASC
  LIMIT 1;
```

**Scenario 2:** Based on your example, you're actually searching for the lowest `start_date` after `CURRENT_DATE`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM patient AS pa
  JOIN patient_coverage_list AS pel ON pel.patient_id = pa.id
  WHERE pel.group_id = $1
    AND pel.start_date > CURRENT_DATE
  ORDER BY pel.start_date ASC
  LIMIT 1;
```

Note that you don't need to filter out the results from the previous query because that data set will never intersect with this data set (see the comparisons of start_date and `CURRENT_DATE`).

**Scenario 3:** Here we need to help us out with a nested query that tells us whether there is any entry with `end_date` after `CURRENT_DATE`. If there is, the query returns empty set due to the `AND` relation, otherwise it returns an entry with the highest `end_date`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM patient AS pa
  JOIN patient_coverage_list AS pel ON pel.patient_id = pa.id
  WHERE pel.group_id = $1
    AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                       FROM patient_coverage_list AS pel1
                       WHERE pel1.group_id = $1  -- important if you want to make comparison within the same group_id
                         AND pel1.end_date > CURRENT_DATE
                   )
  ORDER BY pel.end_date DESC  -- you don't mention what is meant by the "last date", if you meant start_date or end_date
  LIMIT 1;
```

Note that it's better to use `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM ... WHERE ...)` instead of `WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM ...)` so that the RDBMS doesn't need to create data set of the nested `SELECT` and then comparing it to the outer `SELECT`. Use the nested SELECTs wisely.

Comment: The problem is that the scenarios needs to be excluded in that way those escenarios is included

Comment: Do you mean that those three selects should actually exclude the data from a resulting set? If so, what is the problem then?

Comment: if the first escenario is valid on the second escenario no need to show that the patient of the first escenario.